# OpenGL 3.0+ with glew C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, glew

I want to develop a C++/CLI class library with an UserControl for OpenGL rendering.
I've created the WinForm panel with [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16051/Creating-an-OpenGL-view-on-a-Windows-Form).

For testing I have a C# WPF project which has a WinFormHost to use the renderpanel.

This works fine but I only have access to OpenGL 1.0. So I decided to use GLEW.
I've downloaded GLEW, copy the files in the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\" and linked it. 
As additional dependencies I declared OpenGL32.lib, glew32.lib, gdi32.lib, users32.lib

When i try to call glewInit() the test program doesnt start and it throws a FileNotFoundException (my dll isnt found)

Any idea where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late but did you try to copy glew32.dll in the same dir as your executable? eg $(ProjectDir)bin\Debug. That did it for me...

Comment: That's a comment. Wait more rep before commenting via answers.